# How to read and replace string in a file in VB?

Tags: vbscript

Unfortunately my VB knowledge is very minimum, but i need a script to do the following:
I have a file Licenses.txt, which contains one license per line:
`License 1`
`License 2`
`License 3`

I have an other file response.ini, which has a value `ProductKey` in this format : `ProductKey=XXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX`

I want to do the following:
Read from Licenses.txt the first license. If it is free (a license is free if after the license don't stay `Used`), then it should replace the `XXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX` value in response.ini and put `Used` after the first License, so in License.txt it should stay `License 1 - Used`. If i run it again, then it should use the second license and put `Used` after it etc. If i don't have any free License then i should get an ErrorMessage.

Hopefully you can understand what i want to do. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the script which will do exactly what you want.

```
Dim oFSO : Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Read the licence.txt file
Dim f : Set f = oFSO.OpenTextFile("Licence.txt", 1)
Dim sData : sData = f.ReadAll
f.close

'Find next available licence
licenceKey = ""
Dim sLine : for each sLine in split(sData, vbNewLine)
    if (lcase(right(sLine,7)) <> " - used") then
        licenceKey = sLine
        exit for
    end if
Next

if (licenceKey = "") then
    'Show error if no licences are available
    msgbox "No available licences! ", vbOkOnly + vbexclamation, "Licence"
else
    'Write a Response.ini file
    Set f = oFSO.OpenTextFile("Response.ini", 2, true)
    f.Write licenceKey
    f.close

    'Mark the licence as used
    sData = replace(sData, licenceKey, licenceKey & " - Used")

    'ReWrite the licence.txt file
    Set f = oFSO.OpenTextFile("Licence.txt", 2)
    f.Write sData
    f.close
end if
```